# My loop for class? lost

Tags: python

> Simulate a cash register as it totals a user's purchases. The program should execute for an unspecified number of items for a single user. The program should prompt the user for the quantity and unit cost of each item. The user should indicate the end of purchases by entering a negative quantity. The program should output on one line the quantity, unit cost, item total (the quantity times the unit cost), and the current subtotal to the file `purchases.txt`. These values should be separated by a space. The program should output the final total to both the file and the screen.

I have the file I/O down pretty well. What I'm having trouble in class with is creating my loops and making them stop when something is entered.

```
import os.path
outFile = open("purchases","w")
quantity = raw_input("What is the quantity of the item")
cost = raw_input("How much is each item")
outFile.write()
while quantity <= ???? :
```

I understand the math but the loop just loses me.

Comment: It strikes me that you're not actually asking a question anywhere... This is likely to get closed.

Comment: well that will loop as long as quantity <= ?????  ....

Comment: @isaac Please don't add the homework tag. It is obsolete and in the process of being removed.

Comment: @Bart Thanks, didn't get the memo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hint:

> The user should indicate the end of purchases by entering a negative
>   quantity.

The loop should loop until the user will enter a negative quantity.

Therefore your loop would look like:

```
while quantity > 0:
```

Comment: I'm just going to vote to close.

Comment: Your help is great Codemonkey. Thanks

Comment: i figured it out, I was putting less than though, this helped.
Thank you as well Codemonkey, alot of help.